# HTML/CSS - Mysterious Top Padding that doesn't go away

Tags: html, css

I am making a column layout with CSS, and it is coming along swimmingly. Surprisingly enough my question is not about how to make the columns work; That is functioning. But I am instead getting an eerie mysterious "padding" at the top of my columns that is pushing down content. I have prepared an example here :

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ciel/VLGfn/)

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="main">
    <div id="left">
        <div>menu items</div>
    </div>
    <div id="center">
        <h3>Not at the Top!</h3>
        
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <header>Right Top</header>
        <article>Right Body</article>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the relevant CSS:

```
#top {
    background-color: #25282b;
    height: 64px;
}
#main {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
#left, #center, #right {
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0px;
}
#left {
    width: 150px;
    background-color: rgba(38, 46, 51, 1);
    color: #7d8285;
}
#left div:first-child {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
#center {
    width: 228px;
    background-color: rgba(57, 65, 71, 1);
    color: #999ea1;
}
#center div:first-child {
    padding: 15px;
}
#center div:first-child h3 {
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
#right {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#right header {
    background-color: #3e7aa5;
    height: 92px;
}
#right article {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

I'm really not certain what is causing it. The second column just gets outright pushed down a bit, and then the third one gets pushed down as well, regardless of the rules I specify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that `#right` is a `table-cell` element, you could add `vertical-align:top` to it in order to solve this. For what it's worth, this wasn't padding, it's just the way these elements are rendered as the default behavior is to align to the default value `baseline`.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/E3JD6/)

```
#right {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Aha! Perfect, this is exactly what was wrong. Thank you; I'll award credit as soon as stackoverflow lets me.