# Divs do not align with each other

Tags: html, css

I have two divs in which they should be side by side. But once I add a padding to the input box in the left div, the right div shifts.

Any idea why?

The html and css is in the fiddle as below

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <div style="display:inline-block;width:350px;height:200px;background-color:rgba(43, 171, 145, 0.54);margin-right:30px">
        <div style="text-align:left;height:30px;font-size:21px;padding:5px 0px 0px 10px;letter-spacing:7px;font-weight:bold;color:white;background-color:#2bab91"><u>NEW USER</u></div>
        <div style="
            /* text-align: left; */
            padding-top: 20px;
            width: 100%;
            ">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="(Email)" style="
                width: 90%;
                /* margin: 10px; */
                height: 30px;
                ">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;width:350px;height:200px;background-color: rgba(193, 89, 97, 0.61);margin-left:30px">
        <div style="text-align:left;height:30px;font-size:21px;padding:5px 0px 0px 10px;letter-spacing:7px;font-weight:bold;color:white;background-color:#c15961;"><u>EXISTING USER</u></div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="(Email)">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cAJgq/

Comment: Add `vertical-align: top;` to the elements.. http://jsfiddle.net/Ua9dV/

Comment: I would have posted that as an answer, but this is a frequent solution. I already posted the same answer on another question today.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414350/html-css-mysterious-top-padding-that-doesnt-go-away/21414392#21414392 and multiple others this week.

Comment: Just for fun, and to help my html/css I redid the code to minimize the html and put the CSS in one file. http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/cAJgq/8/

Answer (score 2):

Add `vertical-align: top` to the div styles

Answer (score 0):

Your code aren't clean... Put your css into css file it's better to see clearly your html code

```
                        <div style="display:inline-block;width:350px;height:200px;background-color:rgba(43, 171, 145, 0.54);margin-right:30px">
                        <div style="text-align:left;height:30px;font-size:21px;padding:5px 0px 0px 10px;letter-spacing:7px;font-weight:bold;color:white;background-color:#2bab91"><u>EXISTING USER<</u></div>

                        <div style="padding-top: 20px;width: 100%;">
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="(Email)" style="width: 90%;height: 30px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                            <div style="display:inline-block;width:350px;height:200px;background-color:red;margin-right:30px">

                                <div style="text-align:left;height:30px;font-size:21px;padding:5px 0px 0px 10px;letter-spacing:7px;font-weight:bold;color:white;background-color:#c15961"><u>NEW USER</u></div>

                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="(Email)" style="width: 90%;height: 30px;margin-top: 20px;">
                    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cAJgq/1/